# Add specific text after the values which is coming from DB in list box

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a window form that contains listbox and textboxes. listbox contains some values.
i.e 
Friendly letter,
harsh letter, 
test 1 
etc.

these values coming from database by binding property.
i have a column in table fIsTemplate .if fIsTemplate is true than related row's column letter name is a default letter.

i am using nhibernate create criteria for retrieving the data.

ex.
Friendly letter and harsh letter is default template.
So i have to add "(Default)" text after both of the letter name in listbox and when i select any of them letter only letter name should appear in textbox.And when i edit letter name only edited letter name save into the database not with (Default) text.